# How to determine cause of crash from windbg output?

Tags: .net, exception, clr, windbg

I am trying to work out why an application is crashing on a particular machine.

When the application crashes it says the fault module is `kernel32.dll`.

See the output below from `windbg`.  It seems to be crashing on the call to `MyClass.Start`.

How can I work out the actual cause of the crash in more detail?

```
ModLoad: 69840000 69a05000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web.Services\b66225f7bf51912a34f21181b36f800f\System.Web.Services.ni.dll
ModLoad: 68180000 68cdc000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web\88803928914c8cc4b21ca1ad19f3d40f\System.Web.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6e0c0000 6e0d0000   Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
ModLoad: 10840000 10850000   Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
ModLoad: 6e0c0000 6e0d0000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
ModLoad: 10890000 109af000   vbc.exe 
ModLoad: 6e500000 6e646000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\browseui.dll
ModLoad: 6ed70000 6eda0000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DUser.dll
ModLoad: 6e010000 6e020000   MyDll.dll
ModLoad: 101e0000 101f0000   MyDll.dll
ModLoad: 6e010000 6e020000   C:\Program Files (x86)\AppName\MyDll.dll
ModLoad: 69690000 69835000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualBas#\268869655c671d09c3af0f81165da32e\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll
03/10/2013 21:49:50: MyClass.Start: started
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1b48.1b84): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=109cf4c0 ebx=e0434f4d ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=109cf548 edi=19033980
eip=7575d8cb esp=109cf4c0 ebp=109cf510 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll - 
kernel32!RaiseException+0x59:
7575d8cb c9              leave
0:027> g
WARNING: Continuing a non-continuable exception
(1b48.1b84): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=109cf4ec esi=00000000 edi=746a4bd4
eip=77ba0004 esp=109cf04c ebp=109cf4f8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77ba0004 cc              int     3
0:027>
```

Here is the output from `!printexception`:

```
Exception object: 0934bc08
Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    10DCF63C 715FE2AF System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)+0x85997f
    10DCF6DC 70DA4830 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])+0x50
    10DCF710 10BC8E2D Microsoft_ReportViewer_WinForms!Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.OnRenderingComplete(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessThreadResult, Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.PostRenderArgs)+0x5d
    10DCF72C 10BC8DB9 Microsoft_ReportViewer_WinForms!Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessThreadArg.OnComplete(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessThreadResult)+0x11
    10DCF734 10BC4EB3 Microsoft_ReportViewer_WinForms!Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingThread.ProcessThreadMain(System.Object)+0x38b
    10DCF790 739838E2 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)+0x72c8b2
    10DCF79C 7326051F mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x6f
    10DCF7B4 7375D43A mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)+0x4a

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131509
```

Answer (score 2):

Kernel32.dll is where the CLR Exception is being raised (this is the exception that's raised to the outside non-managed world on *any* exception in a CLR app) and that's why the runtime sees it as the cause of the problem, but of course it's not.

if you can run Windbg on the target machine and attach to the process that uses this dll,there is a rather excellent article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-breaking-on-an-exception-part-1.aspx) that shows how you can break on exception and see the actual stack trace for the exception + print out some details of it, this should help to pinpoint the part of your managed code that's falling down.

Answer (score 1):

The output show a managed exception on thread 1b48.1b84. The `!threads` command from SOS/PSSCOR shows exceptions on each thread as well.

The output also indicates that you are currently on the failing thread, so `!printexception` (also from SOS/PSSCOR) will give you the managed exception on that thread.

Comment: See my edit to the question. I have added the output from `!printexception`. Does this indicate a problem with the `ReportViewer`?

Comment: It shows that you have an `InvalidOperationException` and the message tells you why that happens in general. As I don't know your code, I cannot tell you the specific reason though. You might want to inspect the first chance exception to get additional details.